# How do you add x-axis text labels to a 2-D Clustered Bar Chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

[Graph I'm Trying to Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1gk3.png)

I am trying to create a a 2-d clustered bar graph in excel similar to this image - image in link above. I can't add the text I need for the x axis values.

I've tried following these instructions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukloNXrFyB4
but when I get to the end I have the labels on the x axis but no labels on the y axis (I adjusted these instructions so the outcome would be for an x-axis change, not y-axis change).

Would appreciate any advice or links to instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to add a Scatter with Smooth Lines and Markers, and set the data label as some data preset via using "**=**". Please refer to the Step 7.

Step 1. Create data for the auxiliary Scatter.

[image]

Step 2. Create a 2-D Bar chart, besides, check the box of "**Categories in reverse order**" for vertical axis.

Step 3. Move the chart title to left upper corner, set white for its text.

[image]

Step 4. Right click the chart > Select Data > Add, just select any range of data as Series values.

Step 5. Right click the bar of new series > Change Series Chart Type > Combo > Choose the Scatter with Smooth Lines and Markers > OK.

[image]

Step 6. Right click the marker of new scatter > Select Data > choose new series of scatter to Edit, select pre-set data for X and Y values. Meanwhile, check the box of "**Categories in reverse order**" for the second vertical axis.

[image]

**Step 7**. Select the markers of the scatter, right click them > Add data labels. Selete the labels one by one, change the data labels to be text as your needs via "=". Move them to the correct location.

[image]

Right click the bars > Add Data Labels > Do the same steps for these labels to show Direct Report, Peer and etc. Move them to the correct location.

Step 8. Do some small settings.

- Delete tow vertical axis.
- Delete the connecters under the labels.

[image]

- Select the Plot Area > set light grey for border. It fills the line between 0 and 1 on horizontal axis.
- Select the left vertical axis > right click it > Add Major Gridlines.
- Select the series of scatter > set "No line" and "None" for marker at
  the right format panel.
- If needed, you may set white as fill color for title box, then
  move it to cover "0" on horizontal axis.

[image]